# What is probability that two persons are befriended in a social network?

Tags: probability, network

I'm having difficulties to estimate the probability that two individuals are befriended with each other in a social network. Considering that out of a network of 153.111 people (knots), we recrutied 217 individuals. What are the odds that two individuals know each other in that network consisting of the 217 individuals? Can someone please give me a hint how to calculate this, as my probability skills are rather weak :-)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean 153,111 people?

Comment: Without any knowledge of the probability that two people in the network know each other, that can't be answered.

Comment: Yes, I mean 153.111 people. If we allege that for instance the probability that two people in the network know each other is 0.5 (50%), can we then answer the question? Thank you.

Comment: @s.singh: In the USA, we would write 153,111, yes. But other places in the world would write that as 153.111. See here for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{217}2=\frac{217\cdot 216}2=23436$ pairs of people.
The probability that they all fail to know each other is
$$(1/2)^{23436}$$
The probability that there is at least one pair that *does* know each other is then
$$1-(1/2)^{23436}$$
This is very close to one. For instance $2^{10}=1024>10^3$ gives $2^{20000}>10^{6000}$ so the answer is
$$0.999\dots $$ with at least 6000 nines before anything other than a nine!

Comment: The 153,111 has nothing to do with it, as I understood the question